# Rey wears dark goggles in dark environments?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, rey

Why does Rey wear dark goggles *inside* a dark, poorly lit star destroyer? After all, she's using a flashlight to help her see, so wouldn't just taking off the goggles make things easier for her?

[image]

Other than giving the movie suspense for about 45 seconds by not revealing Rey's identity, is there an in-universe answer for this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2LTL8KgKv8

Comment: I don't have any sources for this, but I don't think those are sunglasses. They're probably more like protective glasses in case there are toxic gasses or things like that inside the broken ships. Once she has verified that there aren't, she takes them off.

Comment: Or maybe they're like dakvision or augmented-vision goggles

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Star Wars: Force Awakens - Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary) Rey's headgear consists of a set of stormtrooper lens goggles as well as a headlamp.

The [film's novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel)) described them as "protective" and notes that she removes them once clear of danger (e.g. once she's outside the salvage zone)

> *One such individual clung insectlike to a dark metal wall pimpled with
>   protruding sensors, manipulators, and other decaying mechanisms. Clad
>   in light protective goggles with green lenses, face mask, gloves, and
>   gray desert clothing, the busy figure was burdened with a substantial
>   backpack.*

and

> *Outside the metal caverns and at last clear of danger, the scavenger
>   shoved the goggles up on her forehead and squinted at the blasted
>   surroundings.*

[image]

Answer (score 8):

They aren't sunglasses, they're the lenses of a stormtrooper helmet.

[image]

From [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rey):

> Part of her gear included goggles from stormtrooper helmet lenses[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QJWW.jpg) that Rey salvaged from a ship

The lenses protect her eyes from any harmful particles that may be in the air.

Comment: Also, it's bright at the *top*, and it probably isn't convenient to remove them halfway down.

Comment: Do you know if the goggles actually darken her vision?

Comment: @JoshB. Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Good answer though :)

Comment: @RogueJedi Do we know if the wookieepedia source is good?

Comment: @hatandboots It links directly to the Visual Dictionary, so I'd say yes.

Comment: @RogueJedi - As you can see [below](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121914/20774), the Visual Dictionary doesn't speak to *why* she was wearing them.

Answer (score 4):

## Eye protection

As [Janus said](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121889/rey-wears-dark-goggles-in-dark-environments/121891#comment300251_121889), they are not sunglasses; they're protective glasses/goggles. Jakku is a sandy planet and Rey would need to wear eye protection when walking or using her speeder through sandstorms and such. She also does a lot of hands on work which can sometimes necessitate the use of eye protection.